# Does inheriting class-specific memory (de)allocation methods make the class non-POD?

Tags: c++

If a C++ POD class inherits a class that does nothing except provide [class-specific memory (de)allocation methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), then does that make the POD class non-POD?

For example, with

```cpp
struct Myalloc
{
   static void* operator new(size_t size);
   static void operator delete(void* p);
   // ... complete the set of operators
};

struct X : Myalloc {
  int y;
  double z;
};
```

is `X` a POD type?  It is a POD type if it doesn't inherit `Myalloc`.

Also, do I need to define a virtual destructor for `Myalloc`?  I expect not, because `Myalloc` provides no data members and only static methods.

Do the answers depend on which C++ standard (e.g., C++03, C++11, C++17, ...) is used?  Our code needs to compile on multiple operating systems so we must write to the lowest C++ standard supported between them, which is C++03 with parts of C++11.

The reason for these questions is that I (unfortunately) need to make our own classes/structs use our own memory allocation routines, and it's a bad idea to globally replace the default memory allocation routines.  Our code base has ancient roots and some of it still uses `realloc` to extend the size of a buffer holding a sequence of POD values.  If that POD type turns non-POD when I make it inherit `Myalloc`, then I expect I'll need to explicitly construct the non-POD values, rather than just allocating memory for them.  This would mean a full redesign of those ancient parts of the code, rather than just replacing `realloc` with our own version.  I cannot afford the considerable additional time for a full redesign right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived class will not be a POD type.  A POD type is defined in C++03 as

> **9(4):** "A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-define copy operator and no user-defined destructor. Similarly a POD-union is an aggregate union that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-define copy operator and no user-defined destructor.

Since it is defined as a aggregate if we look at how that is defined we have

> **8.5.1(1):** "An aggregate is an array or class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10) and no virtual functions (10.3)."

and we can see that it explicitly disallows having a base class.  This means you cannot have POd type that is derived from some other type, not matter if that type is POD or not.  C++11 does not change this as aggregates still cannot have base classes.

Comment: A very useful answer, but not the one I was hoping for.

Comment: @LouisStrous Sorry for the late reply but for what it is worth "POD" types can have bases in C++17.  Not sure if that will help since you say you need C++03/11 compatibility but I figured I point it out.